# Cassandra incremental backup

Tags: cassandra, backup

I have taken  full backup in cassandra using nodetool snapshot command. It work completely fine. Now I want to take incremental backup I have enable incremental backup in Cassandra.yaml. Now 
what next i have to do to take incremental backup?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean - you want to transfer only not modified files, or what?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I want to know what step need to do for incremental backup .